# Render Razor MVC in console not work after migration to ASP Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

We are migrating from Asp Core 2.1 to Asp Core 3.1, all are working fine but a stupid command line tool used to test "Razor to String" doesn't work. This command line tool save in a file some view from a razor library ad we are using for testing purpose.

The view engine render is not able to find the view:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
'Unable to find view 'Pages/Emails/TicketNewMessage/TicketNewMessageHtml.cshtml'. 
The following locations were searched:/Pages/Emails/TicketNewMessage/TicketNewMessageHtml.cshtml'
```

The location is correct and it is working perfectly on ASP Core 2.1 and when we call the library from the ASP core 3.1 app , it is still working.

Form Us, the issue is probably on the setup of the render:

```
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var applicationEnvironment = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
        services.AddSingleton(applicationEnvironment);

        var appDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var environment = new HostingEnvironment
        {
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name,
            ContentRootFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(appDirectory),

        };
        services.AddSingleton<IHostEnvironment>(environment);

        services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.FileProviders.Clear();
            options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(appDirectory));
        });


        services.AddSingleton<ObjectPoolProvider, DefaultObjectPoolProvider>();

        var diagnosticSource = new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
        services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(diagnosticSource);
        services.AddSingleton(diagnosticSource);

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddSingleton<RazorViewToStringRenderer>();
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        return provider.GetRequiredService<RazorViewToStringRenderer>();
```

What is missing?

Best regards

Comment: Where is this view named 'TicketNewMessageHtml.cshtml' being called?

Comment: Check the binary output folder to see if the 'cshtml' file exists. If it doesn't, it's probably that you're compiling the views into the DLL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1